# Move point in one buffer to the same line number as the point in a different buffer

Tags: emacs

**The problem**: I have two buffers split side-by-side. I move to a line in the left buffer and I want to do *something* which moves the point in the right buffer to the same line number. For example, if I'm on line 26 in the left buffer I run a macro of some kind and voila I'm on line 26 on the right buffer.

Things I've tried which haven't worked as I liked (or at all):

- `scroll-all-mode`. It works if the buffers are in sync to begin with (e.g. point is on the same line number in both buffers) and if I stick to basic line movement. But it quickly loses sync if I `isearch-forward-regexp` or page-up/page-down. If there was a command which could "resync" then this solves my problem.
- Saving current line number in a register and using that register value in `goto-line`. Saving and restoring positions always goes back to the same buffer.

Comment: If you don't actually require point to move (and `hl-line-mode` can make up for this somewhat), I've noticed that the `2C` autoscroll feature keeps the buffers in lock-step far better than `scroll-all-mode` does. Combining the two doesn't have the desired effect, sadly. See `M-: (info "(emacs) Two-Column") RET`

Comment: @Ben Are you saying that you want to compare two buffers/files? If so, using `ediff-files` or `ediff-buffers`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This piece of Emacs Lisp should do what you want:

```
(goto-line (line-number-at-pos) (window-buffer (next-window))
```

To bind it to a key sequence,

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c l")
  (lambda ()
    (interactive)
    (goto-line (line-number-at-pos) (window-buffer (next-window)))))
```

Comment: You can also create a minor mode which rebinds your `C-n` and `C-p` keys that allow you to move through both the buffers in lockstep.