# Mirroring location in file in two opened buffers side by side

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am trying to find a package/function in emacs where it would have both files opened side by side to be at same line location mirroring the movement of whichever buffer is moving.
Meaning, for two buffers opened side by side, moving in one of the buffers  (page up/down, moving cursor.,..etc) would have the same movements in the other buffer.

More specifically, when opening a buffer (and while activating this mode) the opened buffer should already be at the line position of the one that is already opened in the other buffer window.

Comment: No. This is something completely different.
I usually open the mercurial ediff of a specific file in the second buffer, it includes the developer name and date when he last changed each source line. the original buffer will be colored and the mercurial one won;t because it starts with the names and treated as a text file. I want to have both files navigate at the same lines when moving between them so I can connect the "colored" source line from the original buffer to the "uncolored" mercurial one in the next window. Not sure if that clears it up or added more confusion.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286459/move-point-in-one-buffer-to-the-same-line-number-as-the-point-in-a-different-buf

Comment: Thank you Ben, that is actually very close.
But since when opening both buffers the lines has to be alined, your suggestion won't be a complete fix.
Because I could be at the bottom of the buffer and when doing "C-c l" the second buffer will align in the middle of the screen and so I won't have both lines on the same horizontal level.
I will also want the second buffer to mirror the movements in the first buffer, page up/down, cursor moves...everything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try `scroll-all-mode`. This switches on parallel scrolling of all windows of one frame.

Scrolling with the mouse and scroll bar do not work for me. But all scrolling with keys (such as <kbd>Pg-Down</kbd>, <kbd>Pg-Down</kbd> and cursor movements) works fine.

EDIT:
You could also try the following code. It works only for a frame with exactly two windows not counting the minibuffer. You have to open the files at first and make sure that they are shown in two windows side-by-side. Then define the master window by activating `sync-window-mode` for it. Make sure that line-wrapping is off for both windows.

EDIT: Fixed a problem (sometimes one had to press buttons twice to sync).
Solution: Also hook to `window-scroll-functions`. At `post-command-hook` the right `window-start` position is not known since `redisplay` did not run yet. The fist point where the future `window-start` is known is at `window-scroll-functions`.

```
(defun sync-window (&optional display-start)
  "Synchronize point position other window in current frame.
Only works if there are exactly two windows in the active wrame not counting the minibuffer."
  (interactive)
  (when (= (count-windows 'noMiniBuf) 2)
    (let ((p (point))
      (start (or display-start (window-start)))
      (vscroll (window-vscroll)))
      (other-window 1)
      (goto-char (min (max p (point-min)) (point-max)))
      (set-window-start (selected-window) start)
      (set-window-vscroll (selected-window) vscroll)
      (other-window 1)
      )))

(define-minor-mode sync-window-mode
  "Synchronized view of two buffers in two side-by-side windows."
  :group 'windows
  :lighter " ⇕"
  (if sync-window-mode
      (progn
    (add-hook 'post-command-hook 'sync-window-wrapper 'append t)
    (add-to-list 'window-scroll-functions 'sync-window-wrapper)
    (sync-window))
    (remove-hook 'post-command-hook 'sync-window-wrapper t)
    (setq window-scroll-functions (remove 'sync-window-wrapper window-scroll-functions))
    ))

(defun sync-window-wrapper (&optional window display-start)
  "This wrapper makes sure that `sync-window' is fired from `post-command-hook'
only when the buffer of the active window is in `sync-window-mode'."
  (with-selected-window (or window (selected-window))
    (when sync-window-mode
      (sync-window display-start))))

(provide 'sync-window)
```

Next, a version that synchronizes lines instead of character positions.

If you select some lines in the master buffer this also marks the corresponding lines in the slave buffer. The highlighting keeps permanent until you select another region in the master buffer. It even survives deactivation of `sync-window-mode` in the master buffer. You get ride of the highlighting by

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `sync-window-cleanup`

in the slave buffer.

```
(defface sync-window-face ;; originally copied from font-lock-function-name-face
  '((((class color) (min-colors 88) (background light)) (:foreground "Yellow" :background "Blue1"))
    (((class color) (min-colors 88) (background dark)) (:foreground "Red" :background  "LightSkyBlue"))
    (((class color) (min-colors 16) (background light)) (:foreground "Blue" :background "Yellow"))
    (((class color) (min-colors 16) (background dark)) (:foreground "LightSkyBlue" :background "Yellow"))
    (((class color) (min-colors 8)) (:foreground "blue" :bold t))
    (t (:bold t)))
  "Face used to highlight regions in `sync-window-mode' slaves."
  :group 'sync-window)

(defvar sync-window-overlay nil
  "Overlay for current master region in `sync-window-mode' slaves.")
(make-variable-buffer-local 'sync-window-overlay)

(defun sync-window-cleanup ()
  "Clean up after `sync-window-mode'."
  (interactive)
  (if (overlayp sync-window-overlay)
      (progn
    (delete-overlay sync-window-overlay)
    (setq sync-window-overlay nil))
    (remove-overlays (point-min) (point-max) 'sync-window-slave t)))

(defvar sync-window-master-hook nil
  "Hooks to be run by `sync-window' in the master window ")

(defun sync-window (&optional display-start)
  "Synchronize point position other window in current frame.
Only works if there are exactly two windows in the active wrame not counting the minibuffer."
  (interactive)
  (when (= (count-windows 'noMiniBuf) 2)
    (let ((p (line-number-at-pos))
      (start (line-number-at-pos (or display-start (window-start))))
      (vscroll (window-vscroll))
      breg ereg)
      (when (use-region-p)
    (setq breg (line-number-at-pos (region-beginning))
          ereg  (line-number-at-pos (if (looking-back "\n") (1- (region-end)) (region-end)))))
      (run-hooks 'sync-window-master-hook)
      (other-window 1)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (when breg
    (sync-window-cleanup)
    (overlay-put (setq sync-window-overlay (make-overlay (line-beginning-position breg) (line-end-position ereg))) 'face 'sync-window-face)
    (overlay-put sync-window-overlay 'sync-window-slave t))
      (setq start (line-beginning-position start))
      (forward-line (1- p))
      (set-window-start (selected-window) start)
      (set-window-vscroll (selected-window) vscroll)
      (other-window 1)
      (unless display-start
    (redisplay t))
      )))

(defvar sync-window-mode-hook nil
  "Hooks to be run at start of `sync-window-mode'.")

(define-minor-mode sync-window-mode
  "Synchronized view of two buffers in two side-by-side windows."
  :group 'windows
  :lighter " ⇕"
  (if sync-window-mode
      (progn
    (add-hook 'post-command-hook 'sync-window-wrapper 'append t)
    (add-to-list 'window-scroll-functions 'sync-window-wrapper)
    (run-hooks 'sync-window-mode-hook)
    (sync-window))
    (remove-hook 'post-command-hook 'sync-window-wrapper t)
    (setq window-scroll-functions (remove 'sync-window-wrapper window-scroll-functions))
    ))

(defun sync-window-wrapper (&optional window display-start)
  "This wrapper makes sure that `sync-window' is fired from `post-command-hook'
only when the buffer of the active window is in `sync-window-mode'."
  (with-selected-window (or window (selected-window))
    (when sync-window-mode
      (sync-window display-start))))

(provide 'sync-window)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I am using that already, but I want a mode where both buffers are instantly synced, even if one if mid way in the file and the other was just opened.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Now, it includes a `sync-window-mode` which hopefully does meet your needs. It does not synchronize views when you open the other buffer but when you define the master window. After that it tries to keep the slave in sync with the master.

Comment: I found some time to fix the problem with the point going out of view. (Thanks to my patient wife.) It would be very nice of you if you could test.

Comment: Thank you very much for the hard work. And greetings to your wide.
Just so I understand how to use your code: I assigned f6 to be sync-window:
(global-set-key [C-M-f6]        'sync-window)
Then I am guessing that I will use that only to sync both windows the "afterwards" use scroll-all-mode for syncronized scrolling between the already synced buffers.

Comment: If that is the case then yes, it worked on identical buffers flawlessly.
However, the reason I wanted to use this is to sync mercurial "blame" file with the original file. Meaning there will be the original file in one buffer and the second buffer will include the same source code but for each line it is proceeded with info who edited the line last and the date. The blame file has no colored source code thats why I want to use the original on the side (which is colorized".

Comment: Unfortunately, when there is some more letters proceeding each line your code doesnt sync both buffers on the exact line number. I am guessing you are counting the number of letters? not sure.
But thanks again for trying, and I truly wish you could fix the code to work with what I have.

Comment: I have added a version that synchronizes lines instead of character positions. It does a bit flicker because of the `redisplay`. You do not need to manually synchronize. Just make sure that master and slave are displayed side by side (only two windows!) put point into the master and input `M-x sync-window-mode` and press `return`. If you move point in the master buffer the slave will move along.

Comment: Excellent!
That worked.
One last thing, is there a way to turn the mode off?
Would be awesome if "like scroll-all-mode" when executing the same command it turns itself off.
-> sorry, it does actually turn itself off :)
Thank you so much.

Comment: One last question and out of curiosity.
What does (provide 'sync-windows) do?
And did you actually mean:
(provide 'sync-window)

Comment: I have updated the line-version. It avoids the flicker. The `provide` is the couterpoart of `require`. With `provide` we tell emacs what he has and with `require` we tell emacs what we want.

Comment: I am being greedy :)
Based on what you implemented, could you add the ability to when you shade/select text in master, the same lines get shaded/selected in the slave?

Comment: You know the fairy tale of the fisherman and his wife? :-)) Note, that if I had more time I would organize it in another way: Associate a list of `sync-window-slaves` to the `sync-window-master` and put them under `sync-window-slave-mode`. If this mode is switched off then the highlighting is removed.

Comment: Sorry, my last comment was not very explicit. I have edited my second code snippet. Now it highlights the lines of the active region also in the slave-buffer. In a real package this should be optional. (Let us say a toggle-button in the minor-mode-menu.)

Comment: Don't know how to thank you. I am mystified and (sorry) that my question did not get higher votes, but I have searched all over the web for such solution and never found one.
Much appreciation.

Comment: The only thing that I found missing is to have the highlighted lines (with the mouse) be highlighted at real time in the slave buffer.
I found myself needing an extra "left click" for the text to appear.
It works flawlessly when highlighting using the arrow keys.

Comment: Yes, that is the way it is. The region is highlighted in the slave when it is an active region in the master. Fiddling with mouse tracking is AFAIK not possible in the context of our problem. For mouse-tracking you have to be in the `track-mouse`-form (see `C-h f track-mouse`) but `sync-window` is event driven (i.e., called at special events determined by emacs itself).