# In split window emacs, how to search the "other buffer first line" for ":" then shift the border of the original buffer to that point

Tags: emacs, elisp

I use blame-mercurial using the monky.el package.
In a split window, when activating blame the results come up in the other window with info about the line changed (author/changeset/date:).
I would like to have a command that searches the first line of the "result" buffer, get to where the mark ":" is and shift the border of the original buffer up till that point.

```
Basically, if the borders of both windows are:
| ......                        | ......              |
Before executing the command:
|author 4543 11-27-2013: int x; | int x;              |
After executing the command:
|author 4543 11-27-2013:| int x;                      |
```

The reason for this is I would like to keep the coloring of data types/functions...etc while seeing who last changed these source file lines.

In the blame resulted file, when the lines are proceeded with author changeset date. they loose their coloring.
So I want to use the info for each line from the blame buffer "side by side" with the original fontified file.

I also can't use a fixed window border shift value, because depending on the author(s) name length for each file the position of ":" will change accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have modified the last version at
"[Mirroring location in file in two opened buffers side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19987071/mirroring-location-in-file-in-two-opened-buffers-side-by-side/20143275#20143275)"
such that the following code makes sense. If you run the code below and then switch on `sync-window-mode` for the `mercury-blame` buffer then `isearch` will have the desired effect.

```
(defun mercury-blame-resize ()
  "Resize mercury blame window to blame string at point only."
  (interactive) ;; for debugging
  (window-resize (selected-window)
         (- (save-excursion
              (beginning-of-line)
              (skip-chars-forward "^:\n"))
            (window-width) -1)
         'horizontal 'ignore-fixed-size))

(add-hook 'sync-window-master-hook 'mercury-blame-resize)

(add-hook 'sync-window-mode-hook '(lambda ()
                    (setq-local isearch-update-post-hook #'(lambda () (set-window-hscroll (selected-window) 0)))))
```

Version for emacs 23:

```
(defvar mercury-blame-resize-min 5)

(defun mercury-blame-resize ()
  "Resize mercury blame window to blame string at point only."
  (interactive) ;; for debugging
  (save-excursion
    (beginning-of-line)
    (let ((n (skip-chars-forward "^:\n")))
      (when (looking-at ":")
    (condition-case err
        (enlarge-window (- (max mercury-blame-resize-min n)
                   (window-width) -1)
                'horizontal)
      (error))))))


(add-hook 'sync-window-master-hook 'mercury-blame-resize)

(add-hook 'sync-window-mode-hook '(lambda ()
                    (set (make-local-variable 'isearch-update-post-hook) #'(lambda () (set-window-hscroll (selected-window) 0)))))
```

Helper for testing (without mercury):

```
(loop for i from 1 upto 100 do
      (loop for j from 0 upto (random 20) do
        (insert (+ 32 (random 20))))
      (insert ":\n"))
```

EDIT: In version for emacs 23: Only re-size mercurity blame buffer when there is a ":" on the current line.

Comment: hmmm...I tried that but I keep getting "symbol function definition setq-local is void"

Comment: Would I need to add loading isearch.el?

Comment: Ah, you are still using 23.X. `setq-local` is 24.X. Hm, that is bad since `isearch-update-post-hook` is actually a global variable. Just for trying you can `(make-variable-buffer-local 'isearch-update-post-hook)` on top-level and then replace `(setq-local ...)` with `(setq ...)`. But this will not be free from side-effects. Maybe, you have to restart emacs. Please, tell me wether it works. Then it would be worth a thought. If it works we can check in the `isearch-update-post-hook` whether the current buffer is in `sync-window-mode`.

Comment: No, there is a better solution which should also work on 23.X! `make-local-variable`. I will implement it right now. But, you must test it, because I do not have 23.X.

Comment: I tried it. Nothing happened.
And when I manually do M-x mercury-blame-resize in the blame window I get:
Symbol's function definition is void : window-resize

Comment: I added a version for Emacs23. I found an old computer where I tested it. It should run and show the principle. Maybe, you need to refine it and adopt it to your purpose.

Comment: You should not get problems with `window-resize` since you only use the code marked with `Version for emacs 23:`. Execute this code additional to the stuff from `sync-window-mode`. Afterwards activate `symc-window-mode` for the `mercury-blame`-buffer (*not for the other one!*). Then `isearch` for the wanted name in the `merury-blame` buffer. Okay, the problem here could probably be that you actually want to search for something in the original source code buffer. If so, tell me. To use `M-x mercury-blame-resize` manually in the `merury-blame` buffer you shouldn't have to change anything.

Comment: Be careful! It is not foolproof yet. This is due to my limited time-budget. You can always escape by `M-x sync-window-mode` deactivating the monster...

Comment: I was wondering if it is possible to add an enhancement where if ":" was not found to no resize the window at all.
The reason being, sometimes I would mistakenly check blame on "new" files that has no version yet, and hell breaks loose and would be very hard to recover.

Comment: Another cool thing would also be to have blame window also act as a master for the original file window when focus switch to it, the reason is sometimes you want to search for a specific user and what he changed using blame window and want the other window to move accordingly. So it would be sort of like pairing these two files when one become master when focus switch to it. Before you ask again, I did read the fairy tale of the fisherman and his wife ;)

Comment: Now, in emacs 23-version re-sizing is skipped when there is no ":" on the current line. I am currently working on a large and time-consuming project. Therefore, the cool thing must wait. But it sounds like you did activate sync-window-mode for the wrong window. If you activate it in the mecury-blame window isearch for names should be possible.

Comment: You are right, I am activating sync-window-mode in the other window (not blame window) the reason is that I usually browse code and so want the original file be the master. But sometime, I would like to search for a specific user who changed something in the file and would then switch focus to the blame window, but then will lose the syncing power.
There is no rush on any of this, what you provided me was more than I hoped for, the new stuff are "nice" to have but not a must.
Thanks again for all your support and work. Wish you the best in your project.

Comment: I might also need to add that I did not use the hooks you provided, they did not work for me for some reason. The only way I got it to work is include (mercury-blame-resize) as a last statement in (sync-window) function. And then inside my customized blame function I added the call to (sync-window-mode). So I am honestly not sure of how isearch would have helped me.

Comment: Hi Tobias...I am just checking to see if you have some spare time to look into a way to have the blame window acting as master in the same way, Basically I would like to have both windows synced, so scrolling in one window would scroll the other as well.

Comment: I keep this in mind. I am just very busy. I am planning to put a package on emacswiki.org.

Comment: Tobias, any progress on the other part of the problem I described above? By the way, your solution works flawlessly, been very helpful in my code debug.

Comment: @Ammari I am quite still quite busy with a project. Nevertheless, I did the first step: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/sync-window . All further development/discussion can be shifted there. At first we collect proposals. Feel free to edit the page.

Comment: Hi Tobias. Thanks for the follow up. We were actually able to solve the issue and add the improvement I asked for. Check this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22520337/sync-two-windows