# Sync two windows

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have this code that is "partially" working.
I am trying to sync two windows, so regardless which window you are in the other will sync and start moving accordingly.
The inconsistency I am seeing are around page boundaries; if you move the cursor in one window all the way down till you scroll one more into the next page then directly go up again one line you will notice that both windows will go out of sync. I tried debugging this with no luck. Not sure what is causing this weird behavior.

Here is the code:

```
(defun Xsync-window (&optional display-start)
  "Synchronize point position other window in current frame.
Only works if there are exactly two windows in the active wrame not counting the minibuffer."
  (interactive)
  (when (= (count-windows 'noMiniBuf) 2)
    (let ((p (line-number-at-pos))
      (start (line-number-at-pos (or display-start (window-start))))
      (vscroll (window-vscroll)))
      (other-window 1)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (setq start (line-beginning-position start))
      (forward-line (1- p))
      (set-window-start (selected-window) start)
      (set-window-vscroll (selected-window) vscroll)
      (other-window 1)
      (unless display-start
    (redisplay t))
      )))

(define-minor-mode sync-window-mode
  "Synchronized view of two buffers in two side-by-side windows."
  :group 'windows
  :lighter " ⇕"
  (unless (boundp 'sync-window-mode-active)
    (setq sync-window-mode-active nil))
  (if sync-window-mode
      (progn
        (add-hook 'post-command-hook 'sync-window-wrapper 'append t)
        (add-to-list 'window-scroll-functions 'sync-window-wrapper)
        (Xsync-window)
    )
    (remove-hook 'post-command-hook 'sync-window-wrapper t)
    (setq window-scroll-functions (remove 'sync-window-wrapper window-scroll-functions))
    ))

(defun sync-window-wrapper (&optional window display-start)
  "This wrapper makes sure that `sync-window' is fired from `post-command-hook'
only when the buffer of the active window is in `sync-window-mode'."
  (unless sync-window-mode-active
    (setq sync-window-mode-active t)
    (with-selected-window (or window (selected-window))
      (when sync-window-mode
        (Xsync-window display-start)))
    (setq sync-window-mode-active nil))
  )

(defun sync-window-dual ()
  "Toggle synchronized view of two buffers in two side-by-side windows simultaneously."
  (interactive)
  (if (not (= (count-windows 'noMiniBuf) 2))
      (error "restricted to two windows")
    (let ((mode (if sync-window-mode 0 1)))
      (sync-window-mode mode)
      (with-selected-window (selected-window)
        (other-window 1)
        (sync-window-mode mode)))))
```

Comment: Are you looking for some particular behaviour that isn't provided by `scroll-all-mode` or `follow-mode`?

Comment: Chris, thanks for your input. I usually use this feature with Mercurial blame, win one window I have the original file and in the second I have the blame file "which is basically the same original file with annotations for each line about the developer last changed it and when". I need both buffers to sync on the same "line number". Scroll-all-mode won't achieve that, since either window could be a different line number.

Comment: In `follow-mode`, I call `(sit-for 0)` in the `post-command-hook` to reposition the window to include the cursor, then I rearrange the other windows around it. Maybe you could try a similar trick?

Comment: Lindydancer, I use this mode with Mercurial blame. I would usually browse a file then activate blame and the dual window mode. Both windows will sync at whichever line I am at. When you are dealing with files that has thousands lines of code you don't want to start from the beginning of the file again and search for the lines you are interested in.

Comment: @Ammari, oh, that was not what I was saying. I think the problem you are facing is that Emacs repositions the window when the cursor ends up outside it, but that happens *after* the post-command hook. If you do a `sit-for` you force the redisplay to happen, so that you can get the new window start etc. (Btw, I'm the author of `follow-mode` and I simply tried to explain how I solved a similar problem in that package.)

Comment: I see now what you are saying. Could you provide me with a pointer to follow-mode source code?

Comment: Lindydancer, I included (sit-for 0) in the post-command-hook and it fixed the issue. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Ammari, You're welcome! If you want the source, it's bundled together with Emacs. (Gee, I just realized that I wrote it almost 20 years...) Good luck with your package!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the cursor ends up outside a window, Emacs will reposition the window. However, this occurs *after* the `post-command-hook` is called.

If you call `(sit-for 0)` in your `post-command-hook`, the window will be redisplayed, and you get the new value for `window-start` etc.